# creating a page load counter with innerHTML property

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a webpage that counts how many times it has been loaded. This number is shown to users. I am using localhost MAMP. This is the code I am using:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="counter"> 1 </h1>
    <script>
        function increase(){
            var counterElement = document.getElementById("counter");
            var counter = counterElement.textContent;
            counter++;
            counterElement.innerHTML = counter;
        }

        window.onload = increase;
       </script>
</body>
</html>
```

It increases the counter variable only the first time the page is loaded. On subsequent refreshes is does nothing. The counter just stays 2. What am I doing wrong? I thought that innerHTML property inserts new html into the page. That html doesn't seem to persist during page refreshes. Is there a better alternative way create page counts? It will only be used for personally so bad peformance isn't a problem.

Comment: on each page load your script starts over. you need to remember the counter on the server side, page loads do not have a shared context on the clients.

Comment: Why are you switching between `innerHTML` and `textContent`? Don't use `innerHTML` unless you're actually changing HTML content.

Comment: If you want to count the page loads for a single user you can store the counter value in localStorage, if you want a total number of pages loaded you will need to store the value on the server somewhere.

Comment: yes my intent was to change html content. No attackers will be seeing this page.

Comment: looks like i will search for "localstorage"

Comment: @krompir2 keep in mind that the value is not shared between all the users, that way you are only counting the times a user opens that page (and only he can see it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a counter that uses local storage to count the times you've visited the page:

https://jsfiddle.net/e2q8j1q4/

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<script>
    var n = localStorage.getItem('on_load_counter');
    if (n === null) {
        n = 0;
    }
    n++;
    localStorage.setItem("on_load_counter", n);
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = n;
</script>
```

Note: You'll mostly likely want to use some server-side scripting/storage to do a proper page hit counter (that counts from all users collectively and stores the count permanently).

Comment: Fantastic. It does what I wanted to achieve!

Comment: Don't forget it's good practice to parse strings into integers (localStorage only stores strings), and to not use `innerHTML` since no HTML is being altered.

Comment: @SterlingArcher, gotcha, thank you. I guess for example's sake I was trying to keep that definition line as bare as possible.

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, the script cannot update the actual content of the html page itself.   Since you have set the counter to 1, it will never go higher than 2.

Comment: This... is just wrong. You can parse the text to a number, increment, save to localStorage and replace the content.

Comment: The script he wrote does not do that - that's what I meant by "the script cannot update the actual content of the html page itself"  I agree with you that you can do this the way you mentioned, but he said "I thought that innerHTML updates the contents of the page" - so I'm not wrong - as the script he has will not update the contents of the page.  Do you think it will?